# Invoke the system web browser as a card on BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-ndk

Is it possible to invoke the system web browser as a "card" in Blackberry 10 os?

Trying the code below will launch the browser in a new process:

```
navigator_invoke_invocation_t *invoke = NULL;
navigator_invoke_invocation_create(&invoke);

navigator_invoke_invocation_set_target(invoke, "sys.browser");
navigator_invoke_invocation_set_action(invoke, "bb.action.OPEN");
navigator_invoke_invocation_set_uri(invoke, "http://stackoverflow.com");

navigator_invoke_invocation_send(invoke);
navigator_invoke_invocation_destroy(invoke);
```

Can this be done as a simple card that will roll over my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no card available for the BlackBerry Browser.  You can only invoke the browser as a separate application.